# Redirect all terminal input through command

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, shell

This might sound like a bizarre question, I'm just curious if it's possible. I want to redirect all input to a particular terminal (tilda) through a particular command (man) so that

```
$ ls
```

would bring up the man page for ls.

Does anyone know of any terminal or shell configurations that could make this possible? There's an option for running a custom command instead of the shell, but I'm not sure if it's possible to wait for the user to give an argument for that command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could just do it with a `while` loop like

```
while read -r cmd; do
    man "$cmd"
done
```

then each time you type something and hit enter it'll `man` that